# Unity mesh vertices acces

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

I have a problem when I try to acces a Unity mesh, the same code does't give the same result:(the mesh is a simple cube with 24 vertices)

public class testVertices : MonoBehaviour
{

```
void Start()
{
    Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
    Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;


    Debug.Log(vertices[0].x);
    Debug.Log(vertices[1].x);
    Debug.Log(vertices[2].x);
    Debug.Log(vertices[3].x);
   //the output is 0.5 -0.5 0.5 -0.5


    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log(i);
        Debug.Log(vertices[i].x);
    // the output is 0 0.5 1 -0.5 2 3 4 5 6 ...
    }
}
```

}

It seems that only the first two .x are printed. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: This looks pretty weird, is it exact code you runned ? The debug logs should be the same in the for loop and outside of it

Comment: I edit the script so you can see the exact code I used.  I think the correct answer is removed somehow,  the problem is the Debug.Log regroup the same result, we can unselect the 'Collapse' under the Console to solve the problem

Comment: Yep @Fan, that has to be because of the collaspe option in the console !